# core.img cannot be found

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I get this after trying to reinstall grub using boot-repair:

```
Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of `/dev/sda` and looks at
sector 778209992 of the same hard drive for `core.img`, but `core.img` can
not be found at this location.
```

[Here is the full summary](http://paste2.org/w6ZxkAyN). Basically my computer just boots into Windows EFI without showing the GRUB bootloader. I'm guessing that GRUB is not installed on the EFI boot partition, even though I tried every option. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and Boot-Repair (for saucy) along Windows 8. Also I have an older version of Ubuntu(13.10)

Comment: The grub in the gpt partitioned drive's protective MBR requires a bios_grub partition. That is only for BIOS boot not UEFI boot. But you also show a ubuntu folder in the efi partition for UEFI boot. From UEFI menu can you boot ubuntu entry? Windows 8 likes to set & reset itself as default in UEFI. Toshiba should boot from one time boot key probably f12 or you can do one of the work arounds to let system directly boot grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: please clarify, what you mean "Also I have an older version..."

Comment: Was older version UEFI or BIOS and on same drive? Ubuntu needs an efi partition for UEFI boot on gpt partitioned drives or a bios_grub for BIOS boot on gpt drives. I do not think your older version would have booted in BIOS mode without bios_grub either unless on another drive with MBR(msdos) partitioning.

Comment: I'm not sure how to enter the UEFI menu, I can get to the setup that looks like BIOS setup when you press F2. I also checked Startup and Recovery in System Properties. Windows 8.1 is the only entry there. Let's forget the older version, I'm only aiming to get the GRUB menu back, to log into Windows and Ubuntu 14. Btw, I can get to GRUB by using Super GRUB Live and selecting "manual booting".

Comment: @oldfred when installing ubuntu, I didn't specify a dedicated boot partition. I thought it's something that's taken care of. However I told _boot-repair_ to install grub on the EFI partition.

Comment: You normally do not need a /boot partition. And you just install grub to sda whether UEFI or BIOS. But with UEFI it knows to correctly install grub's efi boot files into the efi partition. Using f2 and a tab or menu for Boot should be the UEFI menu. Toshiba's will boot from a f12 boot menu choice as I understand, but you probably will need the rename of bootx64.efi. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @oldfred thanks for sending me that link. Sorry I missed it in your first comment. `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` fixed everything!

Comment: It is my understanding that with the BCD edit your system reboots into Ubuntu. UEFI does have a one time boot setting, so I assume Windows then resets UEFI to use the one time setting to change to the ubuntu entry?

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with how EFI works, but I think you're right. When you simply enter `bcdedit` in command prompt, it shows you a list of keys and values for (in my case) two boot managers. Apparently the command above assigns GRUB to the "path" entry, stored either directly to the EFI file, or a config file in the same partition. So on boot EFI looks for the "ubuntu" entry instead of Windows Bootloader.